# XML namespace for attributes

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net, xml-serialization

Question: I have an xml element + attributes, which all need to be in a namespace.
I set the element + all attributes into the namespace oai, and I get:

```
<oai:room building="AB" rmName="001">
```

but the XML i need to generate should look like this:

```
 <oai:room oai:building="AB" oai:rmName="001">
```

Why does it remove the oai namespace in the attributes once I set the namespace in the xml element ? Well, I see why, but how do I stop this behaviour, since I need it otherwise?

This is the serialization class I use:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName:="room", Namespace:="http://www.example.com")> _
    Public Rooms As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of cRoom)


Public Class cRoom
    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("building", Namespace:="http://www.example.com")> _
    Public buildingAs String = ""


    <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("rmName", Namespace:="http://www.example.com")> _
    Public rmNameAs String = ""


End Class
```

(oai:="www.example.com")

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try changing your attributes thus:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("rmName",
    Namespace:="http://www.example.com",
    Form := XmlSchemaForm.Qualified)>
```

Comment: Great !
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttribute("building", Form:=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace:="http://www.example.com")> _